# Cannot run .NET Core Angular app through WSL

Tags: asp.net, .net, angular, npm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to learn the basics of .NET Core and I have installed the .NET SDK 2.2 for Linux (I am using Windows Subsystem for Linux). I want to build a Web App with the Angular framework, so I got [this](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/angular-spa)  GitHub repository on my machine with these two commands:

> $ dotnet tool install -g web
>
> $ web new angular-spa ProjectName

Now, basically the next step would be a simple

> npm run dev

but when I try this in bash, I get some errors:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'dev' ]
2 info using npm@3.5.2
3 info using node@v8.10.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info lifecycle my-app@0.0.0~predev: my-app@0.0.0
6 silly lifecycle my-app@0.0.0~predev: no script for predev, continuing
7 info lifecycle my-app@0.0.0~dev: my-app@0.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle my-app@0.0.0~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle my-app@0.0.0~dev: PATH: /usr/share/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/mnt/c/Users/rober/OneDrive/Dev Place/Developer Place/C#/dotnetWSL/angularAPP/AngularApp/MyApp/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH:/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Wolfram Research/WolframScript:/mnt/c/Users/rober/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/rober/AppData/Local/hyper/app-3.0.2/resources/bin:/mnt/c/Users/rober/AppData/Local/GitHubDesktop/bin:/snap/bin:/home/basavyr/.dotnet/tools
10 verbose lifecycle my-app@0.0.0~dev: CWD: /mnt/c/Users/rober/OneDrive/Dev Place/Developer Place/C#/dotnetWSL/angularAPP/AngularApp/MyApp
11 silly lifecycle my-app@0.0.0~dev: Args: [ '-c', 'ng build --aot --watch' ]
12 silly lifecycle my-app@0.0.0~dev: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle my-app@0.0.0~dev: Failed to exec dev script
14 verbose stack Error: my-app@0.0.0 dev: `ng build --aot --watch`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:232:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:24:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
15 verbose pkgid my-app@0.0.0
16 verbose cwd /mnt/c/Users/rober/OneDrive/Dev Place/Developer Place/C#/dotnetWSL/angularAPP/AngularApp/MyApp
17 error Linux 4.4.0-17763-Microsoft
18 error argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
19 error node v8.10.0
20 error npm  v3.5.2
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error my-app@0.0.0 dev: `ng build --aot --watch`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the my-app@0.0.0 dev script 'ng build --aot --watch'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the my-app package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     ng build --aot --watch
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs my-app
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls my-app
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

From what I see here, the npm or node versions are not the latest ones, however, I did an update today just to make sure and the issue is still here.
I would appreciate any help. Please remember that I am new to the concept of .NET web apps and my experience with Angular is also minimal: I recently started to get familiarized.

Comment: Have you run `npm install`?

Comment: Yes I have it installed

Comment: Try to delete your `node_modules` directory and run `npm install` again to re-install the dependencies

Comment: It is taking forever on my Surface Laptop...I will let you know when the install finishes